# Limit of the series $(2\log3-\log2-\log4) + (2\log5-\log4-\log6) + ...$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, logarithms

The series $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} 2 \log(2k+1) - \log(2k) - \log(2k+2) = (2\log3-\log2-\log4) + (2\log5-\log4-\log6) + ...$ converges to a value approximately equal to 0.242 (obtained computing the partial sum with 10000 terms).

I have been playing around but I can't find an explicit formula or link it with a known constant. Do you have any thoughts or ideas?

It is a series of positive terms that tends to zeros. Interestingly, we cannot split the terms in the following way:
$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} 2 \log(2k+1) - \log(2k) - \log(2k+2) = -\log2 + 2\log3 - 2\log4 + 2 \log5 - 2 \log6 + \ldots$ 
This last series does not converge since the terms are growing larger and larger.

Comment: Are you familiar with telescope series?

Comment: Yes, but the terms do not cancel if I'm correct. I am trying again, using your hint, thanks!

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. I deleted my answer since I realised for myself that I was mistaken. Even [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_(n%3D1)%5E(infinity)+log((2n%2B1)%5E2%2F(4*n*(n%2B1)))) is not able to produce a closed-form solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint.

Use $$\frac{\pi}{2}=\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{4n^2}{4n^2-1}.$$

I got the following answer:
$$\ln\frac{4}{\pi}.$$

Indeed, since $\ln$ is a continuous function, we obtain:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left(2\ln(2k+1)-\ln2k-\ln(2k+2)\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\ln\frac{(2k+1)^2}{2k(2k+2)}=$$
$$=\ln\prod_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(2k+1)^2}{2k(2k+2)}=\ln\frac{2}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{4k^2}{4k^2-1}}=\ln\frac{4}{\pi}.$$

Comment: $$\ln\frac4\pi=0.241~564...$$ That is close to $0.240~941...$ but not right.

Comment: @mrtaurho Can you explain why do you think so?

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works, I will write it down properly. Do you have a reference for this identity?

Comment: @Jonathan D See here: ://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product

Comment: Oh thanks, sorry it was easy to find online

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Either I am confusing myself right now but according to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_(n%3D1)%5E(infinity)+%5B2*log(2n%2B1)-log(2n)-log(2n%2B2)%5D) I get about $0.240~941~034...$ for the series but for [$\ln\frac4\pi$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln(4%2Fpi)) about $0.241~564~475...$ and I would claim these two are different.

Comment: @mrtaurho Which says that your WolpramAlpha is wrong. See please my solution.

Comment: I think WolframAlpha does a finite sum to compute the value. When computing the partial sum of the 10'000 terms, it returns 0.24153

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I would be pleased to see a whole solution since honestly speaking I do not know how to apply the given product in this case and hence I am confusing myself right now with the decimal approximation I am not convinced by your value.

Comment: Let me write it down in an answer below!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I apologize for my doubts caused by an invalid numerical approximation. Manually setting the upper limit for the partial sum at 1'000'000 [gives the value $0.241~564~225...$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_(n%3D1)%5E(1000000)+%5B2*log(2n%2B1)-log(2n)-log(2n%2B2)%5D) which agrees nicely with your solution.

Comment: @mrtaurho I added something. You can see a full solution.

Comment: Since the terms are $\Theta(1/n^2)$ I'd expect the error from truncating the sum at $N$ to be $\Theta(1/N)$ - so for truncating after 10000 terms the error would be roughly on the order of 0.0001 (and that's ignoring accumulation of rounding errors but if the calculation is using double-precision numbers I'd expect that contribution to be significantly less).